# Reindex selected _source fields using Rest high level client in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder, reindex, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I want to **re_index only selected fields** from my document in elasticsearch using Rest High level client.

I know the elasticsearch query to achieve that but I don't know it's equivalent query using rest client.

Following is the elasticsearch query which I am trying to implement using rest client -

```
{
  "body" : {
     "source" : {
        "index" : "my source index name",
        "_source" : "id, name, rollNo"
     },
     "dest" : {
        "index" : "my destination index name"
     }
  }
}
```

To write its equivalent query using rest client in java, I have used the following code -

```
ReindexRequest reindexRequest = new ReindexRequest();
reindexRequest.setSourceIndices("source index name").setDestIndex("destination index name");
reindexRequest.setDocTypes("id", "name", "rollNo", "_doc");
client.reindex(reindexRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

But the above code is not working as expected. It's re_indexing all the fields of my document. I want only selective 3 fields to be re_indexed from each doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use below code as `setDocTypes` is not used for source filtering.

As there is no direct method available for setting source filter so you need to change underlying search request suing below code.

```java
ReindexRequest reindexRequest = new ReindexRequest();
reindexRequest.setSourceIndices("source index name").setDestIndex("destination index name");
reindexRequest.setDocTypes("_doc");

String[] include=new String[] {"id", "name", "rollNo"};
String[] exclude=new String[] {"test"};
reindexRequest.getSearchRequest().source().fetchSource(include, exclude);

client.reindex(reindexRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```